# LabelEncoder() : not start from 0

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

For a Keras model, I need to transfrom my labels with LabelEncoder() before make an OneHotEncoding.
Problem : I have 10 classes but LabelEncoder() make the transformation starting from 1 (not 0 as explains by the docuementation). I have so 9 classes at the end (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) not 10.

It's strange because the documentation explains : Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.

It's a problen because ma confusion matrix has a decay of 1 cell !!!

```
# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y)

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)
```

I have for encoded_y :

array([1, 1, 1, ..., 7, 9, 1])

I read all the array and no 0 !!

Comment: Isn't this about `sklearn` and not anything to do with `keras`? You should tag sklearn instead

Comment: Also, don't forget to provide a way to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it that the label encoder starts with 1,

I bet if you do: `encoded_y.index(0)`, it will find the number 0 somewhere.

How did you check that the number 0 is not in your array?